# What is the real names of the User rating column from SharePoint Online and how to retrieve using REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint, spfx, rating

My objective is to display whether a user has rated an item in a list or not. I need to retrieve the User ratings columns from SharePoint Online - see screenshot:
[image]

I'm going to retrieve it using REST through an SPFX webpart.

```
   const columnsToRetrieve =
        `Id, Author/Id, Editor/Id, Editor/Title, Status, Title, Created, LikesCount, LikedBy/Title, LikedBy/Id, LikedBy/EMail, AverageRating`
    do {
        if (!pagedItems) {
            pagedItems = await Web(siteUrl).using(SPFx(context)).lists
                .getByTitle(listName)
                .items
                .select(columnsToRetrieve)
                .expand("Author, Editor, LikedBy")
                .getPaged()
```

I've tried using `Rating, rating, Rates` and several more but none are recognised.
I don't know what the real name is. There is next to no documentation referring to these columns.
Does anyone have any experience working with this column and perhaps could enlighten me?

~I've read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff407954(v=office.14)#retrieving-social-ratings
but it's no help and it refers to SP2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the **internal name** of columns in SharePoint REST APIs.

You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) - you may need to use "Classic experience" method for some of the columns.

Here is the list of columns related to rating settings I have captured using above methods:

| Display Name | Internal Name |
| --- | --- |
| User ratings | Ratings |
| Liked By | LikedBy |
| Number of Likes | LikesCount |
| Number of Ratings | RatingCount |
| Rating (0-5) | AverageRating |

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The real name is Ratings. Why this is poorly documented is typical! :)

Comment: I agree, it is poorly documented feature in the Docs.